# Connecting to Cognex Camera using Open CV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, camera, cognex

My problem is that I need to take a picture from the camera and process it with OpenCV and Python to get coordinates and send them to a robotic arm, but I can't get communication with the Cognex camera with the following code (I got it from the OpenCV documentation):

```
import cv2

cognex = cv2.VideoCapture('192.168.1.5')
while True:
     ret, frame = cognex.read()
     cv2.imshow('Cognex Camera', frame)
     if cv2.readKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
           break

cognex.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but when I run this example I got this error:

```
warning: Error opening file 
(/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:901)
warning: 192.168.1.5 
(/build/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_ffmpeg_impl.hpp:902)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ejemplo.py", line 8, in <module>
cv2.imshow('Cognex Camera', frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.0) C:\projects\opencv- 
python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: 
(-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 
'cv::imshow'
```

and I think it's because it doesn't open the connection with the camera.
I have searched for information on the internet that can help me but I have not be able to find out if it can really connect or cannot connect OpenCV with the Cognex camera.

Comment: I guess you would want `cv2.VideoCapture('http://192.168.1.5')`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, it shows the same error.

Comment: Did you trying to `ping` the camera? Where did you get its address? Have you logged into your router to see the DHCP allocations? Does it serve images over http or rtsp? Is there a port you should specify? Which camera is it? Does Cognex's own software see the camera?

Comment: 1 ) yes, I tried. The IP I set it up in the in-sight explorer software and Im not using a DHCP protocol.
2) I tried with http and rtsp, but no one of this works. Maybe the camera does not support this protocols.
3) The only port that I know about this camera is the 23 but this port is used for a Telnet conecction.
4) The camera is a in sight 7000 gen II
5) Yes, Cognex have a software to get the connection and program the camera.

Comment: I think you should contact cognex about it. AFAIK cognex requires you to use their sdk to connect to the camera (as many other camera providers) and then you would have to convert it to OpenCV image and then you can do your process...

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you found a solution  but you can try the Pleora eBUS SDK which allows you to use cameras from any vendor and integrate with OpenCV. https://www.pleora.com/products/ebus-software/ebus-sdk/